# How to figure out the default item view row height?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qstyle

For a reason I have not yet realized, the out-of-the-box `QTableView` has row height about twice as large as `QTreeView` or `QListView`, at least on my system. I'm trying to figure out the default value Qt is supposed to have for this element type; sadly, the following code gets its second `Q_ASSERT` triggered.

```
QStyle *style = QApplication::style();
Q_ASSERT(style);
QStyleOptionViewItem qsovi;
QRect rect = style->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_ItemViewItemText, &qsovi);
Q_ASSERT(rect.height() > 0); // <- triggered!
```

Obviously, I'm missing some initialization here. The only examples I could find copy the options data from some preexistent object, but I have nothing to copy them from - I need the default for the current style. Suggestions, anyone?

Comment: To set the default row height of a table you can use: `myTable->verticalHeader()->setDefaultSectionSize(size);` So I think you can get it with `myTable->verticalHeader()->defaultSectionSize();` Maybe the problem is that you have to create a table.

Comment: Just checked it: `verticalHeader()->defaultSectionSize()` returns 37 in my case. No kidding. 37 for a simple text table row. It's way too much. However, I do not want to set it to some arbitrary value - it has to be consistent with other item views.